# A problem occurred starting process 'command 'swig' while running OpenVPN Code

Tags: android, ics-openvpn

...

> Execution failed for task ':main:generateOpenVPN3SwigskeletonDebug'

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'swig''

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
> ...
> these are that error while  Executing the Open source [OpenVPN](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn) code tried JDK path change and validate and restart android studio but same issue

Comment: Have you found the solution to this?

Comment: yes, it is because of some file missing when downloaded zip file from GitHub, so have to run git command to import that files